# What should the second parameter of CreateProcess be?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, createprocess

I am trying to start a server using CreateProcess(). Here is the Code:

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    // TODO: Place code here.

    int result; 
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    CreateProcess("C:\\AP\\DatabaseBase\\dbntsrv.exe", "*** WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE***", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    return 0;
}
```

I did not understand from the documentation what the 2nd parameter should be. Can you please help me with it?
Thank You

Comment: Does `dbntsrv.exe` do anything with command line arguments?

Comment: Then you should leave it blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN:

> lpCommandLine [in, out, optional]
>
> The command line to be executed. The maximum length of this string is 32,768 characters, including the Unicode terminating null
>   character. If lpApplicationName is NULL, the module name portion of
>   lpCommandLine is limited to MAX_PATH characters.
>
> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a
>   pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal
>   string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may
>   cause an access violation.
>
> **The lpCommandLine parameter can be NULL.** In that case, the function uses the string pointed to by lpApplicationName as the
>   command line.

So `NULL` is OK there, at least. As soon as you don't pass arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You use it to pass arguments to the .exe defined by the first parameter:

An example would be to call the cmd.exe and then run a script or use a zip utility:

```
void runCmd(const tstring& cmdString, STARTUPINFO &si, PROCESS_INFORMATION &pi)
{
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    tstring cmd_exe_path(win_dir);
    cmd_exe_path.append( _T("\\System32\\") ).append(CMD_PROCESS);

    tstring argline( _T("/c ") );
    argline += cmdString;

    tstring curr_dir( cmdString.substr( 0, cmdString.rfind( _T('.') ) ) );
    curr_dir.erase( curr_dir.find_last_of( _T("/\\") ) );
    size_t pos = curr_dir.find( _T("\"") );
    while(  pos != tstring::npos )
    {
        curr_dir.erase( pos, pos + 1 );
        pos = curr_dir.find( _T("\"") );
    }

    //USE FULL PATHS FOR SAFETY... Include wrapping quotes if spaces required in path
    LOG(LOG_INFO,_T("runCmd(): Calling %s %s Dir[ %s ]"),cmd_exe_path.c_str(),argline.c_str(), curr_dir.c_str());

    if( !CreateProcess( cmd_exe_path.c_str(), &argline[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 
                        NULL,curr_dir.c_str(),&si,&pi ) ) //this generates warning C6335 - resource leak... however handles should be closed by owner
    {
        DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 
        std::string error( "runCmd(): Failed to create Shutdown process - error code is " );
        error.append(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(dw));
        LOG(LOG_INFO,error.c_str());
        throw std::exception(error.c_str());
    }

    LOG(LOG_INFO,"runCmd(): process starting with PID[%d] TID[%d]",pi.dwProcessId,pi.dwThreadId);
}
```