# MysqlDump With ShellExecute Error

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, mfc, shellexecute

When I tried to execute

`mysqldump --host="ean13.info" --user="user" --password="mypass" info_upm > c:\\mysql.sql` 
through ShellExecute in visual C++ I receive

> mysqldump ERROR: can not find table ">".

Execution this command through command line is OK. I understand that something happens with ">" character, but can not find what.

Answer (score 2):

`ShellExecute` is meant to execute the .exe (mysqldump in your case), whereas you're trying to ***also*** use it to redirect stdout to a file. You can't do that with ShellExecute.

[`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) is a better alternative, probably using pipes for the redirection or maybe [`ReadConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958(v=vs.85).aspx).

See:

1. [Redirecting stdout output in cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176746/redirecting-stdout-output-in-cpp)
2. [How do I redirect output to a file with CreateProcess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018228/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-a-file-with-createprocess)